# My Linear Regression model is showing a score of 10 percent, how do i improve it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

AIM- To predict price per square foot of 4 houses, given their 2 features (namely feature1 and feature2). I have 7 houses with feature1, feature2 and price per square foot provided. The last 4 houses have only "feature1" and "feature2". I know what values should be present there. When i compare that with my [redicted values, it is entirely different.

MY CODE - I have a CSV file, that i read and convert it into a pandas data frame from where I train and test the model using LinearRegression.

DATA - Here is the snapshot of my data, this is the data i am using, and I need to predict the last 4 "Pricepersqrft" values.

[image]

PROBLEM- 
I am unable to get an accuracy of more than 10 percent, which means I am not getting the right "Pricepersqrft" for the last 4 houses.

HERE IS MY CODE -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import datasets

csvfileData = THE DATA SHOWN IN THE SNAPSHOT
dataRead = pd.read_csv(csvfileData)
dfCreated = pd.DataFrame(dataRead) #creating a pandas dataframe
print(dfCreated)
# print(dfCreated.head()) #shows first 5 rows of data frame

dfCreated.drop(dfCreated.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace = True)
print(dfCreated)

# where_are_NaNs = numpy.isnan(dfCreated) #previous line displayed Nan where no value was present for "Pricepersqrft column"
# dfCreated[where_are_NaNs] = 0 #use numpy's isnan and set all Nan to 0
# print(dfCreated)
dfCreated.hist(bins = 10, figsize=(20,15)) #plotting histograms using matplotlib
plt.show()

#creating scatter plots 
dfCreated.plot(kind="scatter", x= "Feature1", y="Feature2", alpha=0.5)
correlationMatrix = dfCreated.corr() #computes correlation between 2 columns 
print(correlationMatrix["Feature1"].sort_values(ascending=False))

#value that needs to be predicted
Y= dfCreated['Pricepersqrft']
print(Y)  

#training the model and testing, train_test_split expects both dataframes to be of same length
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(dfCreated, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, Y_test.shape)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
#predictions = reg.predict(X_test)
#print(predictions)
reg.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

The value for the last four "Pricepersqrft" are 105.22, 142.68, 132.94 and 129.71 respectively

Comment: Please note that in the case of regression, `score` does not return accuracy. It returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction. The best possible score is 1.0. So a score of 0.1 might actually be bad, but that might be because you have very few data samples.

Comment: Actually the score is 1.0, I thought it is to be converted to percentage, which in turn means the accuracy. Thank you so much

Comment: @Sruthi V, Apart from that, my concern is that the predicted data is somewhere around "139, 132, 137, 129" for the 4 houses respectively, whereas it should actually be somewhere near to "105.22, 142.68, 132.94 and 129.71" respectively.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using pd.read_csv which returns pandas DataFrame only, so no need to use pd.DataFrame.
2. You are doing train-test random split on whole data, how can you be sure that it is taking last observations as test data?
3. Take all observations for which you want to predict as test data and others as training data. Moreover if the data you are showing here is all you have then prediction may not be good because of less number of observations.

Use iloc for integer location based indexing for n number of rows.

```
train_data = data.iloc[0:m]
test_data = data.iloc[m:n+1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the Data frame thing. Also, in the train test split, I have given test_size as 0.2. I checked by printing the shape of data. And I got 7 as the shape of train data and 4 as the shape of test data. Yes, my data is just 11 observations, and now I know that the data provided is way too less for any computations to be performed. Thank you so much.